# watchPosition fails with react native expo

Tags: android, reactjs, geolocation, native, expo

Hi I'm beginner in React Native, and I used react-native-create-app to generate a react native app.
I'm using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(...) in it
Exactly as in the example here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.24/docs/geolocation.html
(I ejected in order to add geolocation permission in AndroidManifest.xml as described)

When I npm start, and scan the QR code given by Expo, I have the following error

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hdhuc.png)

However, when I'm running the app with react-native run-android instead, it's working well.

But I would like to continue to use Expo, somebody had already encounter this issue or someone see a way to solve it ? Thanks !